# Average of sums in MDX query

Tags: mdx, average

How can I compute average of sums in MDX? I want to compute sum of spending for each person and then compute an average of it. I have the following query so far, but I believe it gives me wrong result:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Average] AS
AVG(Measures.cost)
SELECT [Measures].[Average] ON COLUMNS
FROM
( SELECT Measures.cost ON COLUMNS,
{Person.[Last name].MEMBERS}*
{Person.[First name].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM Cube )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put in the first argument of [Avg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146067) the set of your persons.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Average] AS
    AVG(Person.[Last name].MEMBERS * Person.[First name].MEMBERS, Measures.cost)
SELECT [Measures].[Average] ON COLUMNS
FROM Cube
```

Comment: The result is closer to the right value, but still not there :) The average should be between 100 and 1000, the result was slightly over 4000.

Comment: @kyooryu Could you check that there are no unexpected elements in ``Person.[Last name].MEMBERS``?

Comment: Ah, I copypasted the answer as it was, I did not notice that last name is not crossed with first name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a calculated measure for this function like this

```
IIF (([Measures.cost] > 0), AVG(Person.Members,Measures.cost),null)
```

Then use this calculated measure in your MDX query

```
SELECT Person, 'calculated.measure' 
FROM Cube
```

This is only a sample code to illustrate the function.